# Gajim bug; how to safely upgrade to newest version?

Tags: 14.04, ppa

I'm using Gajim 0.15.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. Quite a few menu items don't response when clicked. For example, under the "Actions" menu, the only items that work are "Start Chat..." and "Quit". Under the "Edit" menu, all items work except "Profile, Avatar".

According to the Gajim website, a newer version (0.16.1) is available, so I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade gajim
```

but 0.15.4 is the newest version available from the official repository.

Assuming this is a Gajim bug (albeit a very low-profile one, as I've been unable to find anything online about it) that's been fixed in the newest version, how can I update Gajim while retaining my current contacts and configuration? Is it "safe" to use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gajim/+archive/ubuntu/gajim-ppa) (i.e., will the old version be removed properly and my configuration preserved)? I usually avoid using PPAs, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gajim/+archive/ubuntu/gajim-ppa) doesn't contains packages for the latest version (currently 0.16.1).

---

A daily package from mercurial is also built. Your settings will be used. But no one can give you a guarantee that a nightly version will be stable.

To use it, remove gajim:

```
apt-get remove gajim
```

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add this line:

```
deb ftp://ftp.gajim.org/debian unstable main
```

and install it by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install gajim-nightly
```

You can get the GPG key of this package by installing gajim-dev-keyring package from the same repository. Just do:

```
suso apt-get install gajim-dev-keyring
```

---

The last option is to compile the application. And your settings will be used there.

Comment: That's a very good point. (On the Gajim site, [they link to that PPA and state](http://gajim.org/downloads.php?lang=en#ubuntu), "If you use Ubuntu universe repository do apt-get install gajim. If you want newer version of Gajim, you can also use this PPA.", so I didn't really look at it and just assumed it was newer. My mistake!) Would building it from the source "play nice" with the existing configuration?